# Button overlaping text in the tour pages

Tags: bug, mobile-web, help-center

I was browsing the [tour page of Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and I encountered this problem in the arrangements of objects, the "Visit the Help Center" button is overlapping some text (I apologize if I am using the wrong terms).

[image: puzzling error]

They instead should have been like this:

[image: so]

This error occurs on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour) as well.

Comment: Does it on [lifehacks.se]?

Comment: I'm not facing the issue, using my laptop or my android device. Maybe your browser is [way too] outdated.